# Problem with figure labelling in Latex

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, hyperref

I am writing thesis in latex and in one chapter figure labels in the text  are not coming right even after labelling figures correctly.

```
\begin{figure*}
\vspace{0.8cm}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{0.465\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{eos9.eps}}
\hspace{0.15cm}
\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{mrgw170817.eps}}
\caption{\small{Pressure versus energy density is plotted  for different compositions (left panel)
and mass-radius relation is exhibited for those equations of state  
(right panel) \cite{gw17}}.}
\end{center}
\label{fig:4a}
\end{figure*}
```

This is first figure in my chapter. It contains two figures together. When I use its label in text e.g.`...\ref{fig:4a}`, I get `...4.2`.

But I should get 4.1 because it is first figure of Chapter 4

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a small comilable code reproducing the problem?

Comment: no one can answer the question in that form. you need to say what input you made, what output you got and what output you intended

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE. Please consider reading the advices in [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Reduce your code into the **M**inimum **E**xample that's **W**orks and still reproduces your error.

Comment: The label goes right after the caption. Here the center env is shielding the figure data so the label cannot get to it.

Comment: Unrelated: don't use the center env here it introduces unwanted extra vertical space. Secondly, `\small ` is a switch, it does not take arguments, additionally sizing like that does not belong in the caption. Captions should be configured globally, here you're just wasting your time

Answer (score 3):

- For reproduce your problem, we need to see MWE (Minimal Working Exampe), a small complete, compilable document as it is (beginning with`\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.
- Providing only fragment of code, as you do, doesn't gives information of used document class, necessary packages in document preamble, which can (mostly do) influence on your problem.
- Regarding your code fragment:

  - it is unnecessary complicated
  - for determine size of images serve `graphicx` option `width`
  - for centering is better to use `\centering` command (placed after `\begin{figure}` (it not introduce additional vertical space as environment `center` does)
  - the figure label is best to be immediately after caption
- Based on guessing about your document, the an MWE, which solve your problem, can be as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text filler
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\begin{document}
\chapter{title}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{figure*}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{eos9}
\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{mrgw170817}
    \caption{Pressure versus energy density is plotted  for different compositions (left panel) and mass-radius relation is exhibited for those equations of state (right panel) \cite{gw17}.}
\label{fig:4a}
    \end{figure*}
see \ref{fig:4a} ...
\end{document}
```

[image]